# unable to create user account in wos2 identity server 5.11

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Dears,

I want to create a new user account (in Primary domain) from wso2is console but I have a error on clicking on finish button. Please could you support to get this user added?

step to reproduce issue:

- [download wos2 identity server 5.11.0](https://wso2.com/identity-and-access-management/previous-releases/)
- start wso2:
  wso2is-5.11.0\bin\wso2server.bat  --run
- login as admin/admin into https://localhost:9443/
- browse to: users and roles -> add -> add new user -> Domain: primary, fill user: Alex, password: **** -> click on finish --> following error triggered, also full logs trace after screenshots:

> Could not add user PRIMARY/alex. Error: Error occurred while accessing
> Java Security Manager Privilege Block when called by method addUser
> with 6 length of Objects and argTypes [class java.lang.String, class
> java.lang.Object, class [Ljava.lang.String;, interface java.util.Map,
> class java.lang.String, boolean]

[image: add user]

[image: error][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0nXL.png)

Error Logs trace:

> [2022-09-22 13:19:35,701] [ebe7cb53-9e5c-473b-bddf-b9f86e9de4a3] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block when called by method addUser with 6 length of Objects and argTypes [class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Object, class [Ljava.lang.String;, interface java.util.Map, class java.lang.String, boolean]
> [2022-09-22 13:19:35,701] [ebe7cb53-9e5c-473b-bddf-b9f86e9de4a3] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.UserRealmProxy} - Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block when called by method addUser with 6 length of Objects and argTypes [class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Object, class [Ljava.lang.String;, interface java.util.Map, class java.lang.String, boolean] org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block when called by method addUser with 6 length of Objects and argTypes [class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Object, class [Ljava.lang.String;, interface java.util.Map, class java.lang.String, boolean]
> at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:222)
> at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:4663)
> at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.UserRealmProxy.addUser(UserRealmProxy.java:802)
> at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.UserAdmin.addUser(UserAdmin.java:202)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
> at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
> at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
> at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
> at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
> at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:170)
> at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
> at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
> at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
> at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
> at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:442)
> at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
> at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
> at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminStub.addUser(UserAdminStub.java:1788)
> at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient.addUser(UserAdminClient.java:94)
> at org.apache.jsp.user.add_002dfinish_002dajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(add_002dfinish_002dajaxprocessor_jsp.java:211)
> at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
> at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:207)
> at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:107)
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.valve.CORSValve.invoke(CORSValve.java:98)
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:102)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
> Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:196)
> ... 83 more
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager$2.run(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:199)
> ... 85 more
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityStoreEventListener.doPreAddUser(IdentityStoreEventListener.java:113)
> at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:4808)
> at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:4696)
> ... 90 more

Comment: Can you add the log trace here? You can find it in IS_HOME/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log

Comment: @PrabakaranThodithotSembiyan I added server logs

Comment: This has failed due to a null pointer in a PreAddListener. Are you running in a windows machine? In that case, when u extract the zip can you make sure all the files have been extracted properly? Sometimes due to long file paths, some files might not appear. Also, check the JAVA version (JAVA 8)? Also make sure that there are no errors when the server is starting. Can you check these?

Comment: Check whether the claim-related config files are there

Comment: you are getting a NPE from https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-governance/blob/e481337c79ac73f3d4ea2c4193fc9602d1e45b01/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/governance/listener/IdentityStoreEventListener.java#L113. By debugging the code you could find the exact reason. Anyway it should be due to claim config issue. Isyou have done any claim config changes recheck. Related question's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57407536/10055162

Comment: The NPE is caused du to fact that one of the pre-conditions on the event framework has not executed. Did you do any changes on the "deployment.toml" on any of the governance or event handlers?

Comment: yes I'm using windows @SomindaGamage. Okay I will check the files

Comment: I found claim-config.xml exists under conf/. Also Im using java 11: Eclipse Foundation_JDK\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot